# Proving that the order of an intersection is a common divisor of the order of both sets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am looking for pointers on a group theory problem. My knowledge is limited to basic group theory, and in the context of my coursework, I believe I am expected to use Lagrange's theorem and other properties of cosets.

> Let *H* and *K* be subgroups of a finite group *G*. Prove that |*H* $\cap$ *K*| is a common divisor of |*H*| and |*K*|.

By Lagrange's Theorem, I know that if *H* $\cap$ *K* is a subgroup of both *H* and *K*, then |*H* $\cap$ *K*| divides both |*H*| and |*K*|. My work so far:

***H* $\cap$ *K* is non-empty:**

Since *H*, *K* $\leq$ G, *H, K* $\neq$ $\emptyset$, and so *H* $\cap$ *K* $\neq$ $\emptyset$. (Am I wrong about this?)

***H* $\cap$ *K* is closed under products:**

Let *a, b* $\in$ *H* $\cap$ *K*

*a, b* $\in$ *H* *and* *K* $\implies$ *ab* $\in$ *H and K* $\implies$ *ab* $\in$ *H* $\cap$ *K*.

***H* $\cap$ *K* is closed under inversion:**

*a* $\in$ *H* $\cap$ *K* $\implies$ *a $\in$ H, K* $\implies$ *a$^{-1}$* $\in$ H, K $\implies$ *a$^{-1}$* $\in$ *H* $\cap$ *K*.

Therefore *H* $\cap$ *K* is a subgroup of both *H and K,* and by Lagrange's theorem, |*H* $\cap$ *K*| divides both *|H| and |K|*.

I do not feel this proof is rigorous. I am not even sure I was right to assume *H* $\cap$ *K* was a group. I think I should have taken an approach more directly involving cosets, but this was not obvious to me at the outset. I would be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $H\cap K$ is a subgroup, it's nonempty, as surely contains the identity element, and Lagrange's theorem applies. 
That's it.